# Longitudal waves. Proof of $\Delta p=B \frac{\partial s}{\partial x}$

Tags: waves, acoustics

I have trouble understanding some derivations about longitudal waves.
I need to derive $\Delta p=B \frac{\partial s}{\partial x}$ from $\Delta p=B \frac{\Delta V}{V}$
knowing that $\Delta V=A\Delta s $ and $ V= A\Delta x$.

Where $B= \frac{\Delta p}{\Delta V/V }$,
$\Delta p$ is pressure difference,
$\Delta V$ volume difference,
$\Delta s$ longitudial displacement caused by wave,
$\Delta x$ is interval of of length of tube filled with liquid.

I don't understand why  $\Delta V=A\Delta s $.

This derivation is needed to derive $\Delta p=Bks_m \sin(kx-wt)$ from $s=s_m cos(kx-wt)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the change in volume of air in that small tube of $\Delta x$ length. So, if at $x$ the displacement of air particles is $s$ and at $x+\Delta x$ it is $s+\Delta s$, how much change in volume has occurred to the column of air that was initially in the $\Delta x$ interval?

Comment: You just paraphrased part of my question.

Comment: No...I'm answering. The new volume is definitely $(A\Delta x-As+A(s+\Delta s))$. So change is $A\Delta s$. Instead of doing it myself, I was giving you a hint.

Comment: Still, I don't understand.

Comment: As I said, $V_{new}=A(\Delta x + \Delta s)$ and $V_{old}=A\Delta x$. So $\Delta V= A \Delta s$.